# Markup reverse to get to original amount?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentile

I am trying to figure out how to mark something up then reverse it.

I am selling an item for $100$ and I need to cover a $15\%$ advertising expense. I want to net $100$ after advertising is paid for.  How do I figure out what percent I should markup the $100$ item to pay for the $15\%$ advertising and still come out with $100$?

Thanks for any help!

Chris Edwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You want to charge $x$ so that $85\%$ of $x$ is $100$.  Can you write that as an equation?

Comment: Would it be 100/.85 = x ?

Comment: That is correct.  I would start with $0.85x=100$, but that is the next step.